# How to validate textbox based on selection of dropdown list in a table row

Tags: jquery

I have three rows of data in HTML table where each row contains drop down and textbox. I want row-wise validation such that:

- When user selects "Absent" in drop down list, the textbox's border should get red. And below "Remarks required" message is displayed.
- When user enters any character in the textbox "Remarks required" message should go off.
- If user has selected "Absent", until and unless she enters the remarks, it should not give permission for second row.

Fidde https://jsfiddle.net/ze05xkmf/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mytable").on("change", "input, select", function() {
    var $selects = $(this).closest('tr').find('td select'),
      $cells = $(this).closest("tr").find("td input");

    $cells.removeClass("has-error");
    $selects.removeClass("has-error");
    $cells.each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().trim() === '') {
        $(this).addClass("has-error");
      }
    });
    $selects.each(function() {

      if ($(this).val() == 'Absent') {
        $(this).addClass("has-error");
        $(".display_error").show();

      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("has-error");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.has-error {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ff0000;
}
.display_error {
  display: none;
  color: #a94442;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  font-size: 85%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <table id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <th>Row</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Remarks</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        Name1
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="YN1" name="YN1" class="target">

          <option value="Present">Present</option>
          <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
          <option value="halfDAY">halfDAY</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="TEXT" id="DATE1" name="DATE1" class="target" />
        <label class="display_error">Remarks required</label>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        Name2
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="YN2" name="YN2" class="target">
          <option value="Present">Present</option>
          <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="TEXT" id="DATE2" name="DATE2" class="target" />
        <label class="display_error">Remarks required</label>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>
        Name3
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="YN3" name="YN3" class="target">
          <option value="Present">Present</option>
          <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="TEXT" id="DATE3" name="DATE3" class="target" />
        <label class="display_error">Remarks required</label>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please check if what my answer has is what is your expected output?

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: Ya.. when i going to enter any message in remarks textbox the error message should go and when error message is there rest rows should be non functional these two criteria not yet solved

Comment: in the updated 1) there is no error message when i select absent, when text box border still red , permission of second still there

Comment: " it should give permission"... What you mean by 'permission'? Should text boxes in the rest of the rows be disabled?

Comment: @ sinisake you are right

Comment: @jancypradeep Does now my answer work?

Comment: Permission: means whenever i select absent without filling it should not go for second row other than everything is fine

Comment: you also thoroughly check once if i changed again to present error is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should technically display it only when the submit button is clicked. Or, at least, when the user has navigated away after coming. But to solve yours, you can do this using `this` keyword and `.closest()` and `.find()` functions:

```
if ($(this).val() == 'Absent') {
  $(this).addClass("has-error");
  $(this).closest("tr").find(".display_error").show();
}
```

Use this event handler for removal of the error message:

```
$(".target").keyup(function () {
  if (this.value.trim().length)
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".display_error").hide();
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mytable").on("change", "input, select", function() {
    var $selects = $(this).closest('tr').find('td select'),
        $cells = $(this).closest("tr").find("td input");
    $cells.removeClass("has-error");
    $selects.removeClass("has-error");
    $cells.each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().trim() === '') {
        $(this).addClass("has-error");
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("has-error");
      }
    });
    $selects.each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 'Absent' && $(this).closest("tr").find("input.target").val().trim().length == 0) {
        $(this).addClass("has-error");
        // Change here:
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".display_error").show();
        // Add these lines:
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("has-error");
      }
    });
  });
  // Add these lines:
  $(".target").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.trim().length !== 0)
      $(this).closest("tr").find(".display_error").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.has-error {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ff0000;
}
.display_error {
  display: none;
  color: #a94442;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  font-size: 85%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <table id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <th>Row</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Remarks</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Name1</td>
      <td>
        <select id="YN1" name="YN1" class="target">
          <option value="Present">Present</option>
          <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
          <option value="halfDAY">halfDAY</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="TEXT" id="DATE1" name="DATE1" class="target" />
        <label class="display_error">Remarks required</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Name2</td>
      <td>
        <select id="YN2" name="YN2" class="target">
          <option value="Present">Present</option>
          <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="TEXT" id="DATE2" name="DATE2" class="target" />
        <label class="display_error">Remarks required</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Name3</td>
      <td>
        <select id="YN3" name="YN3" class="target">
          <option value="Present">Present</option>
          <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="TEXT" id="DATE3" name="DATE3" class="target" />
        <label class="display_error">Remarks required</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: See in your coding if condition gets failed when first select absent then again select present the remarks required messages is not removed

Comment: @jancypradeep I can propose a different way as well. It checks for the right ones... But I guess my approach will almost be similar to what you have right now. Cheers. Let's see... Give me a shout if you have a better idea or if you need any other coding stuff.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the answer**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select').on('change', function() {
 if ($(this).val() === 'Absent') {
       $(this).closest("tr").find("td input").addClass("has-error").focus();
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".display_error").show();
       }
       else
       {       
     $(this).closest("tr").find("td input").removeClass("has-error");
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".display_error").hide();
       }      
}) 
});



$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".txt").keyup(function(){
     $(".display_error").hide();
      $(".txt").removeClass("has-error");
    });
});
```

```css
.has-error {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ff0000;
}
.display_error {
  display: none;
  color: #a94442;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  font-size: 85%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <th>Row</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Remarks</th>
    </tr>
   
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Name1</td>
      <td>
        <select id="statusDDN" name="astatus" class="target">
          <option value="Present">Present</option>
          <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
       
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
     <input type="text" id="remarksID" name="remarks" class="txt" />
        <label class="display_error">Remarks required</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    
    
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Name1</td>
      <td>
        <select id="statusDDN" name="astatus" class="target">
          <option value="Present">Present</option>
          <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
       
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
     <input type="text" id="remarksID" name="remarks" class="txt" />
        <label class="display_error">Remarks required</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Name1</td>
      <td>
        <select id="statusDDN" name="astatus" class="target">
          <option value="Present">Present</option>
          <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
       
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
     <input type="text" id="remarksID" name="remarks" class="txt" />
        <label class="display_error">Remarks required</label>
      </td>
    </tr>    
  </table>
</div>
```